# How do i set the default instance of Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql

I have Sql Server 2000 and Sql server 2005 installed on the Server. How do i set the default instance to 2005?

On Running this script

```
Select @@Version
```

i get:

```
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.194 (Intel X86)   Aug  6 2000 00:57:48   Copyright (c) 1988-2000 Microsoft Corporation  Personal Edition on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)
```

Comment: Please pay better attention to formatting your post and creating meaningful question titles.

Answer (score 3):

The type and name of a SQL Server instance is defined during its setup; each system can have one default instance and as many named instances as you want; when multiple instances are installed on the same computer, they can use different product versions, as in your case. More details [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174516%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

The instance configuration can't be changed after installation; the only way to change this is by uninstalling and reinstalling the instance.

This is valid for all versions of SQL Server, including 2000 and 2005.

Answer (score 2):

What Massimo said;  you can't rename instances without reinstalling.  However, I read your question as, "How do I connect to 2005?"

You can connect to non-default instances by finding the instance name in Services (if you don't remember what you named them).

For example:

[image]

You'd connect to that one by putting YOURSERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS in the connection dialog.